# Any good introductions and resources for gettext?

Tags: gettext

I'm looking into frameworks for translation, and have been considering gettext. Because it's supposedly quite good, and lots of projects use it. Now I read part of the official manual, but it sucked. I kind of have an idea how it works now, but I have no idea where to get started.

In particular my project spans C++, Lua and Javascript, so I'd love to be able to unify the i18n with a single tool, but I'm also not having luck finding gettext good support for Lua or Javascript, are they supported, has anybody used gettext with these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this [tutorial](http://oriya.sarovar.org/docs/gettext_single.html)? Another [example](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html) is at O'Reilly.

Comment: +1 for O'Reilly its a good starting point